# How to mend a broken coil in a DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor

I'm trying to repair a bread making machine (A Tefal/Moulinex OW500530). At the start of the program (kneading), it drives the brushed DC motor (ZYT4245-23) in short pulses every second. Now and then, the motor won't start. It will start again when I help it a bit, though. A bit further into the program, the kneading is constant (no longer in pulses), and once the motor is spinning, it seems to be working fine.

I've opened up the motor and found out that the coils between two pairs of neighboring commutator plates seem to be broken; I measure about 50 Ohm between the other pairs of neighboring commutator plates, but between these, there is a very large resistance. There are about 20 commutator plates in total.

Could I get the motor running again by simply short-circuiting those two pairs of commutator plates (soldering)? Is it safe?

Comment: Transistors and town hall have collectors, but I've never heard of motors having them.

Comment: @Olin I hope I got it right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think shorting the commutator plates for the dead pole to the adjacent working one (either side should work I guess) may actually be worth trying. 
With more than e.g. 3 poles it should be okay as you won't short across the input as the brushes touch both poles.
Since your motor appears to have a lot of poles it may still work okay if one pole has to cope with twice the angle. At least there will still be field as opposed to it dropping out completely.

Take advice with caution (i.e whatever you try, make sure you do it as safely as possible) as it's hard to be sure of anything in situations like this when you have no datasheet available with relevant info like winding connections. 
Before you apply any power, turn through all poles and test to make sure there are no obvious shorts where there shouldn't be (e.g. across the power input) and resistance doesn't change much from the 50 ohms you measured across the working coils.

Of course, the sensible option is just to buy a new one (for actual serviceable use) as Olin says, but even then I'd probably still hack this one just out of curiosity ;-)

Comment: I shorted across the two broken coils (which were only 3 plates apart), and the motor seems to be operating fine now. Well, it survived two bread-making cycles and didn't burn down the house :) The shorts were made by just soldering the plates together. I suppose the two little solder balls don't bring the motor out of balance too much...

Comment: Recently I had to short across another three broken coils, and it's working again. Let's see how long it lasts this time...

Comment: Probably not long if another 3 have already gone :-( Sounds like it may be time to consider a replacement. If you decide to replace the motor rather than get a new machine, make sure you check any supporting power circuitry for issues that could have caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: My last operation on the motor extended the lifetime of the bread maker by only a couple of weeks, after which I've replaced it with a new one.

Answer (score 2):

If the coil between two connectors has broken (the wire has melted and become open circuit) you will need to remove all the copper wire from that coil and re-wind a new coil.

Not a simple job for the beginner - you will need to get the right grade of copper wire and wind the right number of turns.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not an option. Even if the coils weren't partly covered in a thick layer of glue, I wouldn't go that far to repair it. Any comments on short-circuiting those collectors?

Comment: A short circuit would be a short circuit.  It will cause huge currents to flow and things will start to melt.  Not a good idea.

Comment: But I would short-circuit two adjacent collectors. So instead of the 220V standing across 11 coils, it would stand over 10 coils. Not such a big difference.

Comment: @Brecht Machiels If you short two pieces together, why do you believe that (assuming motor is of such mechanical construction that the two parts of the commutator will always be of same polarity) it will affect operation in any significant way? The coil that was there is dead and it won't make the motor make the step where it gets stuck.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Based on [the drawing on this page](http://www.20sim.com/webhelp/toolboxes/mechatronics_toolbox/servo_motor_editor/theory/basic_principles/brush_dc_motors.htm), I'm thinking it would enable the current to flow through the other coils which can then still generate the force to turn the motor.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what exactly you have measured.  It seems like maybe one of the windings has opened?

If so, opening the motor and replacing the wire is not a reasonable option.  You'll never get it sitting just right into the same space at the same weight.  About the only thing you can hope for that you have half a chance of fixing yourself is if a wire disconnected from one of the commutators.  I saw this happen once in a cheap 12V siren motor.  The wires were poorly soldered down, and about half of them had come loose.  It was tricky getting the soldering iron into the tight space, but soldering the ends of the wires back down fixed the motor.

You also should consider how much a new bread machine costs and what your time is worth.  If you're doing this as a challenge or to learn, fine.  For other reasons it probably doesn't make any sense.  Just get a new bread machine.

Answer (score 1):

The motor's own brushes will short adjacent commutator segments in the normal course of operation; every time a commutator gap moves under a brush, there's such a short. So it seems like it ought to be safe enough to try. Do try to make the connection mechanically very sound, as centrifugal forces will be significant. Loose bits of metal inside a spinning motor are decidedly not safe.

Whether or not the motor will be cured of its no-torque spots is a mystery, but since the unit is already effectively broken, it seems worth a try, as a science experiment. If you want peace of mind, you're better off replacing the motor, or perhaps the entire machine.

Answer (score 1):

Original answer withdrawn for revision as it had a multi-phase mindset.

***Note that shorting adjacent commutator segments*** **may** ***be a bad idea.***

The short that occurs when brushes straddle the commutator gap means that a 
configuration which is becoming less useful due to rotation and a configuration that is becoming more useful are temporarily placed in parallel. This is acceptable.

But, by hard connecting adjacent commutator segments you may be creating connections which did not exist when the brushes are "far away". Whether this happens depends on how the motor is wound.

Better in some cases is to short out comm segment to the one N segments away where this winding is terminated. Whether that is OK depends on how many pole pairs there are. For few pole pairs this will increases the current in that set of coils substantially.

Connecting a Polyfuse across the whole open circuit winding may give the best of all worlds.
 The winding string will still get some current at startup but not draw excess current.
 Polyfuse will need to be rated to be "overcurrent" at winding operating current and will need to be epoxied securely in place and balanced with an opposing mass.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem (2 adjacent pairs were open-cicuit) and glued only one of the pairs. When measuring again, the second pair was not open-circuited any more. I assambled the motor, put some grese on the driving wheels and the bread machine works perfectly.

However, the bread machine was practically new, so such a defect should not appear in a quality product of this brand...